# Google Maps API and geocoding in Crimea

Tags: google-maps

I use Google Maps Apis for geocoding to get full address for coordinates. It worked fine before revolution in Ukraine and the fact that Crimea currently is a part of Russian Federation. As result, nowadays I receive just this:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Geocoding stopped to work for Crimea, Ukraine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214989/google-geocoding-stopped-to-work-for-crimea-ukraine)

Answer (score 1):

FYI I got this answer from Google Support:

> Since Crimea currently is a disputed territory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes), Geocoder results will currently not return results for reverse geocoding.