# Google Maps API v3 doesn't return information on locations in Israeli West-Bank (territories)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Maps API v3 and it works fine in all places except for the Israeli West-Bank (territories).

In the following code:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latLng }, function(results, status) {});
```

When I request information for any Israeli West-Bank location, I get status: `google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS`

Any idea why?
I see that in other google maps applications it shows information about Israeli West-Bank places.
How do they do it?
Is there a bypass?

---

Here is example of location that returns ZERO_RESULTS: 32.105325, 35.172491 (It's in Ariel, Israel)

Comment: An example of location that returns ZERO_RESULTS?

Comment: Btw. the geocoder request has no `latLng` property. It should be `location` to take a `LatLng` object. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest

Comment: MrUpsidown: `geocoder.geocode()` can return results by lat,lng. See example function `codeLatLng()` on this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Geocoding stopped to work for Crimea, Ukraine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214989/google-geocoding-stopped-to-work-for-crimea-ukraine)

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle!
It looks like Israel West Bank is same issue as Crimea... :(

Comment: @DimaL. Well... looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest) it clearly states it should be `location: LatLng object` and not `latLng: LatLng object` but it seems to work with both. Up to you then ;-)

Comment: @MrUpsidown: Right, documentation doesn't mention 'latLng' property, but I used their example and it works fine for all areas except of "Disputed Territories". I just tried to replace 'latLng' property with 'location' property - doesn't make any difference, so it looks like you can use both properties...
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google Maps won't return reverse geocoding results for disputed territories: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes